# Language detection / Character detection with ICU - International Components for Unicode

Tags: c, unicode, icu

I'm trying to do a language detection with ICU. My code works well for ISO-8859-1 (Danish, Dutch, English, French, German, Italian, Norwegian, Portuguese, Swedish). But I don't find how I can detect Korean, Japanese ... language. Can you help me ? My code:

```
void                        languageDetection(char *str)
{
    UCharsetDetector        *csd;
    const UCharsetMatch     *csm;
    const char              *name;  
    const char              *lang;  
    int32_t                 len = strlen(str);
    int32_t                 confidence;
    UErrorCode              status = U_ZERO_ERROR;

    csd = ucsdet_open(&status);  
    if(status != U_ZERO_ERROR)  
        printf("ERROR: in ucsdet_open :%s\n", u_errorName(status));  

    ucsdet_setText(csd, str, -1, &status);  
    if(status != U_ZERO_ERROR)  
        printf("ERROR: in ucsdet_setText :%s\n", u_errorName(status));

    csm = ucsdet_detect(csd, &status);  
    if(status != U_ZERO_ERROR)  
        printf("ERROR: in ucsdet_detectAll :%s\n", u_errorName(status));

    name = ucsdet_getName(csm, &status);
    if(status != U_ZERO_ERROR)  
        printf("ERROR: in ucsdet_getName :%s\n", u_errorName(status));

    lang = ucsdet_getLanguage(csm, &status);
    if(status != U_ZERO_ERROR)  
        printf("ERROR: in ucsdet_getLanguage :%s\n", u_errorName(status));

    confidence = ucsdet_getConfidence(csm, &status);
    if(status != U_ZERO_ERROR)  
        printf("ERROR: in ucsdet_getConfidence :%s\n", u_errorName(status));

    printf("%s (%s) %i\n", name, lang, confidence);

    ucsdet_close(csd);
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: I found a way to check in which block the character belongs: `block = ublock_getCode(utf32string[0]);

 if (block == UBLOCK_HANGUL_JAMO || 
  block == UBLOCK_HANGUL_SYLLABLES ||
  block == UBLOCK_HANGUL_COMPATIBILITY_JAMO || 
  block == UBLOCK_HANGUL_JAMO_EXTENDED_B || 
  block == UBLOCK_HANGUL_JAMO_EXTENDED_A){
  printf("Korean\n");
 }` But I don't like this metode

Comment: What do you mean by "language"? What format is your source data? [`ucsdet_getLanguage`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ucsdet_8h.html#a54b1e448b1d9cce1ac017962aaa801aa) is extremely crude.

Comment: my source is in UTF-8. So I know if my data is in UTF-8 ucsdet_detect doesn't work. For example if my data is  "안녕하세요" my code print: UTF-8 () 100, if my data is  "Hello my friend" my code print: ISO-8859-1 (en) 18.
I think it's more difficult to make the difference between French and English for example,  a Korean charactere has his own byte code and any other language doesn't use the same characrter so why he can't tell me it's in Korean ?
Any way I just need to find a way to make this work with a language who not use Latin alphabet

Comment: You probably want to look at the "[Script](http://unicode.org/reports/tr24/)" property of each character, and make a judgement based on that.